# Unsupported Config Type ""

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

While generating the configtx peer block for Hyperledger Fabric Channel Creation in Amazon Managed Blockchain
Facing an error
CRIT 002 Error reading configuration:  Unsupported Config Type ""
ERRO 003 Could not find configtx.yaml. Please make sure that FABRIC_CFG_PATH or --configPath is set to a path which contains configtx.yaml

Even though I tried export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD still facing same error.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you defined correctly the Fabric config directory. In terminal in the root folder of you HLF configuration just use the command:

```
export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=${PWD}/<folder-with-configtx.yaml-and-crypto-config.yaml>
```

Comment: @Sumeet_Pol make sure you point a folder where these file reside. Also make sure you didn't change default file names in any of your scripts or yaml files.