# How to fix Unsupported Config Type "" error in Hyperledger Fabric on Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://github.com/IBM/blockchain-network-on-kubernetes) on deploying Hyperledger Fabric on Kubernetes. But instead of IBM Cloud, I'm doing it with Google Cloud. I encountered [this same issue](https://github.com/IBM/blockchain-network-on-kubernetes/issues/55) (see my logs below) and tried:

- changing docker image to `docker:18.09-dind` in `docker.yaml`.
- setting `FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD/configFiles` instead of `FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD` in `create_channel.yaml` according to [another StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55537099/unsupported-config-type).

However, these workaround did not work for me and I still encounter the error.

How do I fix this to be able to successfully deploy the network?

```
> ./setup_blockchainNetwork.sh

peersDeployment.yaml file was configured to use Docker in a container.
Creating Docker deployment
persistentvolume/docker-pv created
persistentvolumeclaim/docker-pvc created
service/docker created
deployment.apps/docker-dind created

Creating volume
The Persistant Volume does not seem to exist or is not bound
Creating Persistant Volume
Running: kubectl create -f /home/me/blockchain-network-on-kubernetes/configFiles/createVolume.yaml
persistentvolume/shared-pv created
persistentvolumeclaim/shared-pvc created
Success creating Persistant Volume

Creating Copy artifacts job.
Running: kubectl create -f /home/me/blockchain-network-on-kubernetes/configFiles/copyArtifactsJob.yaml
job.batch/copyartifacts created
Wating for container of copy artifact pod to run. Current status of copyartifacts-dcg4m is Pending
copyartifacts-dcg4m is now Running

Starting to copy artifacts in persistent volume.
Waiting for 10 more seconds for copying artifacts to avoid any network delay
Waiting for copyartifacts job to complete
Copy artifacts job completed

Generating the required artifacts for Blockchain network
Running: kubectl create -f /home/me/blockchain-network-on-kubernetes/configFiles/generateArtifactsJob.yaml
job.batch/utils created
Waiting for generateArtifacts job to complete
Waiting for generateArtifacts job to complete
Creating Services for blockchain network
Running: kubectl create -f /home/me/blockchain-network-on-kubernetes/configFiles/blockchain-services.yaml
service/blockchain-ca created
service/blockchain-orderer created
service/blockchain-org1peer1 created
service/blockchain-org2peer1 created
service/blockchain-org3peer1 created
service/blockchain-org4peer1 created
Creating new Deployment to create four peers in network
Running: kubectl create -f /home/me/blockchain-network-on-kubernetes/configFiles/peersDeployment.yaml
deployment.apps/blockchain-orderer created
deployment.apps/blockchain-ca created
deployment.apps/blockchain-org1peer1 created
deployment.apps/blockchain-org2peer1 created
deployment.apps/blockchain-org3peer1 created
deployment.apps/blockchain-org4peer1 created
Checking if all deployments are ready
Waiting for 15 seconds for peers and orderer to settle

Creating channel transaction artifact and a channel
Running: kubectl create -f /home/me/blockchain-network-on-kubernetes/configFiles/create_channel.yaml
job.batch/createchannel created
Waiting for createchannel job to be completed
Waiting for createchannel job to be completed
Create Channel Failed
```

```
> kubectl get pods
NAME                                    READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
blockchain-ca-58b4bbbcc7-dqmnw          1/1     Running            0          30s
blockchain-orderer-ddc9466d-2sqt8       1/1     Running            0          30s
blockchain-org1peer1-ffbf698bb-fd6nf    1/1     Running            0          29s
blockchain-org2peer1-98f7fb5f9-mb5m7    1/1     Running            0          29s
blockchain-org3peer1-75d6b8bf5c-bxd24   1/1     Running            0          29s
blockchain-org4peer1-675669ffff-b4dxj   1/1     Running            0          29s
copyartifacts-dcg4m                     0/1     Completed          0          60s
createchannel-9wt54                     1/2     Error              0          12s
docker-dind-54767c54c5-crk7b            0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   3          73s
utils-wbpcz                             0/2     Completed          0          37s
```

```
> kubectl logs createchannel-9wt54 -c createchanneltx
/shared
systemd-private-3cbb0a492497473087eda0bb66fbd738-systemd-networkd.service-QHqKfL
systemd-private-3cbb0a492497473087eda0bb66fbd738-systemd-resolved.service-NuNfWF
systemd-private-3cbb0a492497473087eda0bb66fbd738-systemd-timesyncd.service-SzE37R
2021-02-03 08:49:16.970 UTC [common.tools.configtxgen] main -> INFO 001 Loading configuration
2021-02-03 08:49:16.970 UTC [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] Load -> PANI 002 Error reading configuration:  Unsupported Config Type ""
2021-02-03 08:49:16.970 UTC [common.tools.configtxgen] func1 -> PANI 003 Error reading configuration:  Unsupported Config Type ""
panic: Error reading configuration:  Unsupported Config Type "" [recovered]
        panic: Error reading configuration:  Unsupported Config Type ""
...
```

Comment: Are you using GKE or GCE? Something like running `Minikube` or `Kubeadm` on Google Compute Engine and following [this guide](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-implement-hyperledger-fabric-external-chaincodes-within-a-kubernetes-cluster-fd01d7544523) would be enough for you?

Comment: I'm using GKE. I have tried the guide you linked but I have encountered errors too :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FABRIC_CFG_PATH` setting is wrong.
Currently, your error is a phrase that occurs when there is a problem with the syntax in the `configtx.yaml` file or when the **file path is wrong and cannot be found**.

For `configtxgen`, refer to the `configtx.yaml` file under `FABRIC_CFG_PATH`.

---

[In the tutorial](https://github.com/IBM/blockchain-network-on-kubernetes) you provided, `configtx.yaml` is not found under `configFiles` directory and it exists under `artifacts` directory.

I'll suggest two of the easiest solutions out of many.

- move `artifacts/configtx.yaml` to `configFiles/configtx.yaml`

```
mv ./artifacts/configtx.yaml configFiles/configtx.yaml
```

- Or, set `FABRIC_CFG_PATH`  to configFiles

```
export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=${PWD}/artifacts
```